# Where are the /x/ packages from golang.org now?

Tags: go

It seems all packages like golang.org/x/net/websocket was moved away. Are they moved to godoc.org permanently, and where are their sources now?

Comment: you import it using `import "golang.org/x/net/websocket"`. Although, http://golang.org/x/net/websocket redirects to https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/websocket because the docs reside there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since go has moved to Github, their source code is now [there](https://github.com/golang/). So `golang.org/x/net/websocket` sources are at [`https://github.com/golang/net/tree/master/websocket`](https://github.com/golang/net/tree/master/websocket).

Comment: Go 1.4 Release Notes says nothing about moving to github.. https://golang.org/doc/go1.4. Only about code.google.com: "The Go project subrepositories (code.google.com/p/go.tools and so on) are now available under custom import paths replacing code.google.com/p/go. with golang.org/x/, as in golang.org/x/tools."

Comment: There was a [separate announcement](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-dev/sckirqOWepg/YmyT7dWJiocJ). `golang.org/x/...` is the canonical path for those imports now, so it doesn't matter where they're hosted.